# Importing bugs to JIRA from HP ALM

Tags: csv, import, jira, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

My project is closing our HP ALM instance and is switching to JIRA, and I got stuck with doing the import. I am planning to use the CSV import function in JIRA, but I am having some issues. Is there a better way? Preferably free, but I can probably swing a minor expense.

The comments in ALM are in the form of a text field where the comments are inserted after each other and are separated by a header and a footer. Has anyone dealt with splitting them up for import before?

Many of the bugs are also linked to each other by defect number, is there a way to map this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can try JAM plugins and you can map each value from JIRA to HP ALM. Syncs almost real time.

Also, JIRA Bridge for HP Quality Center is available for JIRA 4.0 to 5.2.11. So, unless you installed an old 5.2.11 version, import your issues, then upgrade JIRA, you should find another way.

Hope this helps.